# Should I use sound or noise?

Tags: word-choice

> Sean hurries into the room to hide from the hitman. As he closes the door and the room goes dark, he bumps into something which makes a loud **sound/noise**. Out in the hall the hitman has heard the **sound/noise**. He strides toward the door.

What is appropriate here - sound or noise ?

Comment: Although both words are possible in this context, most likely would be: **Sean did not want to make a SOUND. But when he bumped into something, he made a NOISE.** Here, **noise** implies a greater volume than **sound**.

Comment: For narrative purposes you might want to specify the actual type of noise, such as "clatter," "thump", or "crash."

Answer (score 1):

Sound is generic and technically usable, but noise is more appropriate here, specifically because it implies that the sound is **unwanted**.

From Merriam-Webster:

> 2b: any **sound that is undesired** or interferes with one's hearing
>   of something

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth noting [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heard%20a%20noise%2Cheard%20a%20sound&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheard%20a%20noise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheard%20a%20sound%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cheard%20a%20noise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheard%20a%20sound%3B%2Cc0), showing that *both nouns are about equally common overall...*

[image]

(It's much the same with [*makes a noise / sound*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=makes%20a%20noise%2Cmakes%20a%20sound&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmakes%20a%20noise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmakes%20a%20sound%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmakes%20a%20noise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmakes%20a%20sound%3B%2Cc0), etc.)

---

To the extent that there's a difference, ***noise*** implies ***unwanted sound***.

Often that's because the "noise" is competing with ***wanted*** sound[s] (as in a [*signal-to-noise ratio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio)), or because it's unpleasant / painful to hear (jet engines are *noisy*, not *"soundy"*).

But sometimes (as in OP's context), ***noise*** is the unwanted alternative to ***silence*** (obviously *anything* the hitman might hear would be "unwanted" from Sean's point of view).

---

Thus for OP's *specific* example, ***noise*** is the more "natural" choice. But ***sound*** isn't "incorrect" - it's just a less likely stylistic choice that probably wouldn't carry even a fine nuance of difference.

*However*, it is possible to identify a fairly likely distinction between the noun choices, where they both refer to something that's definitely "unwanted"...

> *[My parents are upstairs, so...]*
>    *...don't make a **noise***
>   *...don't make a **sound***

Obviously the exact circumstances of the person being spoken to would mostly dictate the precise *implication* of the noun choice (I'm sure you can think up some possible scenarios! :) But *by default*, native speakers would understand ***Don't make a noise*** as meaning *Don't make **loud / noisy** sounds*, whereas ***Don't make a sound*** always means *Don't make **any** sounds / noises*.